# Should a Scala DAO get / select method with no arguments (arity-0) have parentheses?

Tags: scala, coding-style, conventions, parentheses, readability

According to the [Scala guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html), methods of arity-0 (no arguments) can and should have their parentheses omitted if:

> the method in question has no side-effects (purely-functional)

That's quite an ambiguous statement to make, isn't it?

I'm trying to figure out whether a DAO with a getter/select arity-0 method should have parentheses or not.

On one hand it should, because accessing a database might be a costly action with "performance side effects"  on the application.

On the other hand it shouldn't, because the DAO trait is unaware of the implementation, and by definition, it's simply a getter method that doesn't alter the state of the application.

What say you?

Comment: If the function is accessing the DB, there is a clear side-effect, so the `foo()` syntax is clearer, even if that's mostly a question of code style there.

Comment: Shouldn't your comment be an answer instead?

Comment: For me there is no answer, as it's mainly subjective.

Comment: How many DAOs can you fit on the head of that pin anyway? Voting to close as mostly opinion

Comment: I don't think this question calls for opinions. The question at hand is whether a database call is purely functional and/or whether it has side effects. The answer, clearly is, that it is not, and it does. This is not an opinion, but a statement of an objective fact. Now, whether or not this means that the method should have parenthesis is, indeed, a question of taste, but that does not seem to be at all what OP is asking, as that decision is deferred to scala guide.

Comment: Side-effects in computing are *very well-defined.*  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Comment: @cchantep: Only if you're writing to the database.

Comment: @Robert According to the definition on Wikipedia, `"a function or expression is said to have a side effect if... or has an observable interaction with... the outside world"`. From what I understand from the Wikipedia page, database access (even read-only) is considered a side effect. Can you confirm that?

Comment: If you write to the database, yes.  If you're just reading from it, no.

Comment: I don't see where you get the notation of "write-only". It explicitly says `Side effects are the most common way that a program interacts with the outside world (people, filesystems, other computers on networks)`. **Interacts**.

Comment: So?  You can also interact without a side-effect.  *Writing* is the key concept here.  Don't get lost; the Scala article is talking about *simple, read-only functions.*  And no, going off to a database doesn't fulfill their no-parens principle, read-only or not.  You still need the parentheses.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see any explicit part of the "formal" definition saying that an interaction with an external resource is only considered a side effect if it's a write-only interaction.

Comment: @Robert On one hand you insist on "side effects are only for write-only interactions with a database", but on the other hand you still simply rule out the no-parenthesis principle for this case. That is, my friend, an inconsistency.

Comment: The side-effects argument is irrelevant; don't get hung up on it, but don't use the words if you don't know what they mean.  Access to a database doesn't fulfill their "no parentheses rule."  It takes a non-trivial amount of time to access a database (read-only or not), so you use parentheses.

Comment: But then, if it's not a side-effect, the principle dictates that one can omit the parenthesis in this case. I don't see any other way of interpreting what is written in that guide.

Comment: I know what it says.  But it also provides two examples that are quite illustrative.  I wouldn't use the non-parentheses variant for a console read either; even though it has no side-effects, you have to wait for it.  Also, it's not referentially-transparent.  The parentheses-free form is intended for simple, read-only, referentially transparent *properties.*

Comment: I think it all boils down to their mentioning of a _purely functional_ method, which aside from not having any side-effects, it is idempotent. Since accessing a database like that isn't idempotent, the parenthesis should stay (not referentially-transparent => not idempotent).

Comment: It appears that you don't know what idempotent means either.  Database *writes* are idempotent.

Comment: Yeah I guess I might have mixed idempotent and referential transparency there, never mind that. Point is, a _purely functional_ method is the at the core of the principle, which isn't only about having no side-effects, correct?

Comment: I like *referential transparency* better.  Functions with side-effects are not referentially transparent.  But don't miss what I said about the two examples.  `queue.size` is a *property,* one that is very unlikely to require changing to a method. And technically it's *not referentially transparent,* since someone can change `queue.size` by adding something to the queue (unless perhaps you're passing around immutable queue objects).  It is side-effect-free, though.

Comment: That is a good point. So, a read-only interaction with a database being not referentially transparent is not the reason why the principle doesn't apply for it. And it's not the side-effect thing, since it has no side effect. So, is it just because of the time taken to complete the request? Or perhaps because it might fail due to numerous factors that are out of the scope of the application? In other words, can you perhaps just answer the question with a clear explanation? :)

Comment: Programmers expect *properties* (which is what a 0 arity method without parentheses is) to *return immediately.*  I define "immediately" as 50ms or less, which generally rules out database accesses.

Comment: 50ms is considered in many cases a very long time for a simple database query. Perhaps time isn't an appropriate factor for such a definition?

Comment: The point is that `queue.size` isn't reaching out to any other services to get its result; it's merely returning a value from an object.  Hence, the "returning immediately" part.  It's a *property.*

Comment: But the guide mentions nothing regarding other services (unless by "no side effects" they also mean no read-only requests to other services). Is the definition of the principle in this guide simply inadequate?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @Robert Finally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Scala 0 arity methods without parentheses are essentially [*properties.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming))

Look at [what Microsoft has to say about properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx).  Substitute "zero-arity method without parentheses" for "property" in the statements below, and it still works, for the most part:

> **Consider using a property if the member represents a logical attribute of the type.**
>
> For example, `BorderStyle` is a property because the style of the border is an attribute of a `ListView`.
>
> **Do use a property, rather than a method, if the value of the property is stored in the process memory and the property would just provide access to the value.**
>
> ```
>     public int Department
>     {
>         get { return department; } 
>         set { department = value; }
>     }
> ```
>
> **Do use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations.**
>
> - *The operation is orders of magnitude slower than a field set would be.* If you are even considering providing an asynchronous version of an operation to avoid blocking the thread, it is very likely that the operation is too expensive to be a property. In particular, operations that access the network or the file system (other than once for initialization) should most likely be methods, not properties.
> - *The operation is a conversion,* such as the `Object.ToString` method.
> - *The operation returns a different result each time it is called, even if the parameters do not change.* For example, the `NewGuid` method returns a different value each time it is called.
> - *The operation has a significant and observable side effect.* Note that populating an internal cache is not generally considered an observable side effect.
> - *The operation returns a copy of an internal state* (this does not include copies of value type objects returned on the stack).
> - The operation returns an array.

As you can see, a property is the *simple case* of returning a value from an object.  A method is essentially *everything else.*

Comment: Seems like the second bullet (operation is a conversion) and the last one (operation returns an array) do not apply in Scala; take a look at the conversion methods of the collections. But the rest seems good to me.

Answer (score 4):

I would also apply [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) as a guideline. Methods which are not referentially transparent deserve `()` to make the user aware.

E.g.

`def randomInt(): Int`

vs

`case class Rectangle(width: Int, height: Int) { def area: Int = width * height }`

(yes, `area` in this case could be a `val` or `lazy val` but that's not the main point)

In your case, getting data from a datasource is not referentially transparent so I'd go for the `()`.

Comment: The Scala style guide cites `queue.size` as a valid example.  Wouldn't that fail the referential transparency test?

Comment: Yes, that would fail it indeed. While I'm a simple developer and not the maintainer of the style rules, I've found this rule helping me and others to write slightly more readable code.